# How to refer more than one url using regex in Java

Tags: regex, url, artifactory

I'm basically trying to make a REST call to the artifactory to get json response about the repositories.
 My URL is something like this "http://127.0.0.1:8081/artifactory/api/storage/deploy/"  where **deploy** is my repository.
Now i want to get the information about all the repositories whose name **starts with  - deploy** .

How to modify the url in-order to get the info about the repositories with name starts with deploy??

Is it possible to do this, without getting all repositories name and then filtering?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is not a java question, rather a question of your rest service supporting such behaviour. I.e your rest api must provide a method to get a list of all the repositories by regexp. 

I don't think this can be solved by means of java in any way other than bruteforcing links.